# Difficulty installing go buffalo using go mod on windows

Tags: go, windows-10, go-modules, gopath, buffalo

I am very new to golang. I am trying to work with the gomod. Trying to explore the go buffalo framework. But finding a bit of difficulty in installing that.

***What I have done:***

1. I saw that go get is nomore supported for buffalo and so switched to go modules.
2. Created a module by `go mod init github.com/webbuffalotest`
3. Fetched `go get -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo` (on the same directory where I have go.mod file)
4. Fetched `go get -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` (on the same directory where I have go.mod file)
5. `go install github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo`
6. I was expecting a buffalo.exe inside %GOPATH%/bin so that I can add it to my path but didn't find one.

My question is what's wrong? Is the exe not installed or it's somewhere else because of go mod. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: go.mod content]

I am using windows 10. I am not willing to install package managers as scoop or choco to install buffalo. Thanks for your patience :)

> Edited:
> Also tried setting `set GO111MODULE=on` but of no use.

> Solved:

***My bad, I should have used `go install github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo` instead of `go install github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo`***

Comment: Have you set the GOBIN environment variable? From documentation, " If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to the directory it names instead of DIR/bin."

Comment: My bad, I should have used go install github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo instead of go install github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo` is a library; the corresponding binary is (aptly-named) `github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo`.

The `go install` command you ran should have warned you about that, but didn't because `go install` used to also be used to cache compiled libraries (it no longer does that in module mode).

I've filed https://golang.org/issue/46912 to add a diagnostic.